# Change the height of hover effect

Tags: html, css

My hover effects aren't exactly aligned with the nav bar. In fact they are slightly wider and I would like to fix that. I've tried some stuff but to no success.

This is how it looks like now:

[image: Picture]

Code:

```css
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url('img/tape-measure.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    height: 1000px;
    color: #000305;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: 'Coming Soon', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', cursive;
    line-height: 1.5;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:link, a:visited {
    color: #CF5C3F;
}

a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #CF5C3F;
    color: #fff;
}

.mainHeader {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


.mainHeader img.Logo {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
    top: 54%;
    width: 15%;
    height: auto;
}

.mainHeader img.Margrit {
    position: absolute;
    right: 5%;
    top: 15%;
    width: 15%;
    height: auto;
}


.mainHeader nav {
    background-color: #9cb34f;
    
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainHeader nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: auto;
    
}

.mainHeader nav ul li {
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
    width: 24%;
}





.mainHeader nav a:link, .mainHeader nav a:visited {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #CF5C3F;
    
    
}

.mainHeader nav a:hover, mainHeader nav .active a:visited {
    background-color: #CF5C3F;
    text-shadow: none;
    
}


.mainHeader nav ul li a {
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    padding: 10px 130px;
    
    
}


.mainHeader p {
    
}


.mainHeader p.inBearbeitung {
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 5%;
    font-size: 150%;
    color: #CF5C3F;
    font-size: 200%;
}



.mainFooter {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 3%;
    width: 90%;
    left: 5%;
    right: 5%;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #9cb34f;
 display: table;

}


.mainFooter p {
    
    color: #fff;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 1%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">
    <head>
  <title>Couture Anni</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coming+Soon" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
  <header class="mainHeader">
   <img class="Logo" src="resources/img/Content%5Cvariation_800_e.png" alt="Logo">
   <img class="Margrit" src="resources/img/IMG_5347_small.jpg" alt="Annamaria Hofstetter">
   
   <nav>
    
    <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>
    
      </nav>
   
   
   <p class="inBearbeitung"><strong>Diese Seite ist in<br>Bearbeitung.<br> Bis demnächst!</strong></p>
  </header>
  
  
        
        <footer class="mainFooter">
     
      <p>Copyright © <a href="#" title="couture-anni">couture-anni.ch</a></p>
     
  </footer>
        
    </body>


</html>
```

Current Problem:

[image: problem]

The text is not in the middle of the nav bar and the spacing is wrong of the hover effects

Comment: Something is not right as you can see in the picture that I added above.
I also edited the code. The problem is described beneath the latest picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your a[tag] needs to be displayed inline-block; and than add height=20px; (your menu height)

```
.mainHeader nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't the hover rule that causes this, but the restriction of the `height` in the rule for `nav`. Erase the `height`setting from `nav` and add `overflow: auto;` to the `ul`(to wrap the `ul` around the floated `li` s)

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url('img/tape-measure.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 1000px;
  color: #000305;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: 'Coming Soon', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', cursive;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #CF5C3F;
}

a:hover,
a:active {
  background-color: #CF5C3F;
  color: #fff;
}

.mainHeader {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.mainHeader img.Logo {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  top: 59%;
  width: 15%;
  height: auto;
}

.mainHeader img.Margrit {
  position: absolute;
  right: 5%;
  top: 15%;
  width: 15%;
  height: auto;
}

.mainHeader nav {
  background-color: #9cb34f;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}

.mainHeader nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  overflow: auto;
}

.mainHeader nav ul li {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 24%;
}

.mainHeader nav a:link,
.mainHeader nav a:visited {
  color: #fff;
}

.mainHeader nav a:hover,
mainHeader nav .active a:visited {
  background-color: #CF5C3F;
  text-shadow: none;
}

.mainHeader nav ul li a {
  border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <title>Couture Anni</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coming+Soon" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="mainHeader">
    <img class="Logo" src="resources/img/Content_variation_800_e.png" alt="Logo">
    <img class="Margrit" src="resources/img/IMG_5347_small.jpg" alt="Annamaria Hofstetter">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <p class="inBearbeitung"><strong>Diese Seite ist in<br>Bearbeitung.<br> Bis demnächst!</strong></p>
  </header>
  <footer class="mainFooter">
    <p>Copyright © <a href="#" title="couture-anni">couture-anni.ch</a></p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you got this issue because the height of several elements, like `<nav>` `<ul>` and `<li>` is smaller than the height of your `<a>`, try to set it to 25px (the actual height of your links) and that should be fine.

Then it should look like this : https://jsfiddle.net/nodedL26/1/

Comment: So, if 25px is the height of my links, can I change it to 20px?
If I set the nav bar to 25px it works but I would like the links to be 20px